# C# .NET MySql only returns last result

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, forms

First off this is my first attempt at C#.
My issue is, regardless of me using datatables, lists, or mysqldatareader; the query only returns one result and only the last result of the table.

My Table Values are(Col names first):
Index City
1     Paris
2     London

My C# last code attempt was:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace MySQL_Sample
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MySql connections
        MySqlConnection connection;
        string host;
        string db;
        string uid;
        string pass;
        host = "localhost";
        db = "sample";
        uid = "root";
        pass = "";
        string ConnectionString = "SERVER=" + host + ";" + "DATABASE=" + db + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + pass + ";";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        //MySql Commands
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //MySql Call back
        while(rdr.Read())
        {
            DataTxtBox.Text = rdr[0].ToString() + " | " + rdr[1].ToString();
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get all the records one by one but the line :

```
DataTxtBox.Text = rdr[0].ToString() + " | " + rdr[1].ToString();
```

has an assignment that gets only current record. Instead try this:

```
DataTxtBox.Text += rdr[0].ToString() + " | " + rdr[1].ToString();
```

The important bit is the `+=`. This means that the rows get *appended* instead of overwriting the previous value.

Comment: This was perfect; also note that

DataTxtBox.Text += rdr[0].ToString() + " | " + rdr[1].ToString();
was changed to:
DataTxtBox.Text += rdr[0].ToString() + " | " + rdr[1].ToString()+"\r\n";